# How can i write a user's input from a text box to the web.config file in asp.net / html?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, web-config

I am trying to obtain a file path that users manually enter on a web page, and then write it to the web.config file.

Comment: Dynamically changing web.config restarts your application, your session objects could be lost, be careful.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you open the web.config configuration file for modification.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig1 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("yourwebconfigpath");
//Do whatever you need to do
rootWebConfig1.Save();
```

Via:  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456.aspx)